# Cannot click on radio button in fieldset

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python with selenium to automate some process but I am having problems to click a radio button. This is the situation:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="cart">
    <form method="post" id="pmntFrm" name="chsPmntRt" action="/cart" class="form-validate">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="payment-field">
                <input onchange="load('payment', 1)" type="radio" name="paymentmethod_id" id="payment_id_1" value="123">
                <label for="payment_id_1" class="">
                    //foo
                </label>
                
                <input onchange="load('payment', 2)" type="radio" name="paymentmethod_id" id="payment_id_2" value="456">
                <label for="payment_id_2" class="">
                    //foo
                </label>
            </div>    
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have tried click on it using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='1']").click()
```

and I receive this error **Message=Message: element not interactable**

Also I read in other thread that maybe the problem is that the fieldset is in a different  but is not.

I really apreciate if someone can help me with this topic.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for the element to be clickable induce a webdriver wait and then click. Also don't use . it's for child elements not root driver.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='radio' and @value='1']"))).click()
```

Or the label

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[@for='payment_id_1']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```